# can i get access in my code to the alarm clock interface

Tags: android

I would like to use the android standard user interface for the alarm clock in my code similar to the way the preferences edit interface can be used.   Is this possible?

Comment: what do you want to do with the alarm clock interface? You could call the alarm clock app but you can't use the interface to set alarms for your own application.

Comment: I want to enable a user to set a time when the alarm will wake up each day inside my app.   I have done the alarm receiver etc but I thought it would save time if the standard interface was useable and also ensure consistency with the device.  Guess I'll have to try to write it.   Is there some way to see the source code for the alarm clock app?   I googled and saw a refernece to \a .git file but couldnt see how to get the readable source code.

Comment: I am doing something similar HERE!! http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13523350/android-alarm-clock-ui

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, sorry, there is no documented and supported API for setting alarm clock alarms. Moreover, that application may not exist on all Android devices, since it is not part of Android.